# Get max values for each index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
Id     timestamp   
W-001  2022-10-15T17:54:47
W-001  2022-10-15T17:55:20
W-001  2022-10-15T17:55:21
W-002  2022-11-11T15:12:43
W-002  2022-11-11T15:12:50
W-002  2022-11-11T15:12:55
W-002  2022-11-11T15:12:57
W-003  2022-11-18T09:35:12
W-003  2022-11-18T09:35:13
W-003  2022-11-18T09:35:17
W-003  2022-11-18T09:35:23
```

I want result to be like this, select ID with the latest timestamp

```
Id     timestamp   
W-001  2022-10-15T17:55:21
W-002  2022-11-11T15:12:57
W-003  2022-11-18T09:35:23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby(by=['Id']).max().reset_index()
```

Comment: Solve my problem perfectly, thank you Isaac!

Comment: No problem! happy to help :) Also, if you could please help me by accepting/approving my answer (clicking the check mark next to my answer), I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: I would love to do that, but unfortunately I can't vote your answer cause I need 15 reputation to cast a vote, once I have enough reputation I will vote your answer ASAP!
Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: No worries, I was just trying to get enough points to get started myself :) but I have enough now, so now I am just happy to have helped!

Comment: @Evantaka You can always _accept_ an answer to your question, there's no rep requirement for that (voting is not the same as accepting).